# Is it posible to return on the line with exception?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

I have a code which looks like this:

```
try:
    a = form['a']
except KeyError:
    pass
try:
    b = form['b']
except KeyError:
    pass
try:
    c = form['c']
except KeyError:
    pass
try:
    d = form['d']
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Is it posible to do something like this:

```
try:
    a = form['a']
    b = form['b']
    c = form['c']
    d = form['d']
except KeyError:
    somekeyword
```

So if there is no key 'a' in form still working and try to find key 'b' and so on

UPD: 
Sorry, my bad. I need to preserve all values not just one of them.
So I need the keyword or something like that that will help me continue try block even after exception raises.

Comment: yes, you can certainly do that.

Comment: you can use `user=form.get('a')`, and when the key does not exist it returns `None` by default...

Comment: You *can* do that, but it will work differently - the former still tries `user = form['b']` whether or not `user = form['a']` fails, while the latter doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `form` is a dictionary you may also use [`.get(key, [default])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) syntax:

```
>>> form = {'d':5}
>>> form.get('a', form.get('b', form.get('c', form['d'])))
5
```

You can make the function calls *lazy* by using some iterators:

```
>>> from itertools import dropwhile
>>> it = (form.get(k) for k in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
>>> next(dropwhile(lambda val: val is None, it))
5
```

---

**edit**: if you need all four:

```
>>> a, b, c, d = map(form.get, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
>>> a, b, c, d
(None, None, None, 5)
```

Comment: [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) is a built-in function, don't use it as a variable name.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid very true! fixed that!

Comment: Note that you can unpack from a list, so `a, b, c, d = map(form.get, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])` also works. And if we're guaranteed that the keys are single chars that can be shortened to `a, b, c, d = map(form.get, 'abcd')`

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do this, assuming form supports full dict semantics, and that None is actually a valid value of the form:

```
sentinel = object()
user = sentinel
for key in "abcd":
    user = form.get(key, user)
if user is sentinel: # I don't know if None is a va
   whatever-you-mean-with-somekeyword
```

Comment: Python supports `for...else` construct so that you don't have to mess with sentinels like this.

Comment: Could you elaborate on where this would help here? AFAIK it's just about running code if there is a break within the loop. What would that help here?

Comment: Sentinels are itself sometimes problematic if the value range is sufficiently large. Early breaking when a suitable value comes up is also often desirable, even though the algorithm won't be 1:1 same any more. And arguably using an explicit construct is a more Pythonic thing to do.

Comment: @progo `sentinel` is a new object, so it cannot appear in `form`.

Comment: @chepner: oh yes... I overlooked that detail that I admittedly haven't used before.